# Redirection for non checkout guest allowed in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

After [Allow guest checkout for specific products only in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322204/allow-guest-checkout-for-specific-products-only-in-woocommerce/64324562#64324562) answer to my previous question, the following code redirect users to login page:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'checkout_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function checkout_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
    if( is_checkout() && !is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

But I have some products which allows guest checkout (see the linked question/answer above). So how could I fix my code for the products which allows guest checkout to disable that code redirection?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec here a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace my previous answer code with the following:

```php
// Custom conditional function that checks if checkout registration is required
function is_checkout_registration_required() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
            // Check if there is any item in cart that has not the option "Guest checkout allowed"
            if ( get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_allow_guest_checkout', true ) !== 'yes' ) {
                return true; // Found: Force checkout user registration and exit
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_registration_required', 'change_tax_class_user_role', 900 );
function change_tax_class_user_role( $registration_required ) {
    return is_checkout_registration_required();
}
```

Then your current question code will be instead:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'checkout_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function checkout_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
    if( is_checkout() && !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout_registration_required() ){
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.